# How to change font on definition's optional title, but not on theorem's optional titles?

Tags: formatting, theorems

My preamble is the following:

```
\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[subsection]
```

The default is set so

```
\begin{defi}[Some defi]
\end{defi}

\begin{teo}[Some theorem]
\end{teo}
```

Outputs both titles [Some xxx] between parentheses. I want to change only the definition title to bold and remove its parentheses. I have tried the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont\textbf{#3}}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
```

Which correctly changes the title font to bold and removes parentheses, but in all cases. I have also tried,

```
\makeatletter
\def\th@definition{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \normalfont % body font
}
\makeatother
```

Which leaves theorem titles as they are, changes definition title font to bold but keeps parentheses.

Finally I tried,

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@definition#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont\textbf{#3}}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
```

Which doesn't work at all. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose your preamble also loads `amsthm`. You should take a look at the `thmtools` package, which provides powerful tools to customise the layout of theorem-like structures, and cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code uses `\pdfstrcmp` to condition on whether `\thmhead` is called as a `definition` or a `theorem`. That way you can format things to suit your needs based on the environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[subsection]

\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{Definition}=0
    \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont\textbf{#3}}}%
  \else
    ~\thmnote{{\the\thm@notefont (#3)}}%
  \fi
  }
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{defi}[Some defi]
\end{defi}

\begin{teo}[Some theorem]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```